# Can you grow tropical plants (ginger) on a hugelkultur in a cool climate?

Tags: temperature, ginger

Ginger is a warm climate plant that can be grown in cool climates indoors with an ambient temperature of 25 - 30C (75-85F).  When you grow plants on the top of a hugelkultur, as long as the trees and other vegetation etc compost, heat is released into the soil.  So, if the soil were to reach that temperature, would that keep the plant alive over mild winter (5 - 10C) , or does the above ground temperature kill the plants?  ( I guess there would be a temperature gradient falling off from the ground upwards ).